# SharePoint Managed Metadata Term Set

Tags: managed-metadata

I have migrated Managed Metadata Application from one farm to another farm by DATABASE backup and restore, however one of the Term Sets is not coming through to the new farm, I can not see any error message or warning.
any idea?
Regards

Comment: Is it part of the Central MMS store, maybe that one term set was created as local?

Answer (score 0):

there was an issue with Permission. after updating the permission it start showing.